# w3 css w3-navbar with w3-top hiding page content

Tags: css, html

Using [w3css](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/) with a pinned navbar (ie enclosed in a  with class w3-top) how can I know the height of the navbar (which will vary with screen size) so I can leave this much space at the top of my non-pinned content so the navbar doesn't overwrite content?

My best solution so far is to duplicate the navbar in javascript and insert that at the top of the page without the w3-top class so that there is a hidden element which is always the same size at the top of the page.

```
...
<div id="pinned_nav" class="w3-top">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-light-grey w3-border">
  <li>

...


<script type="text/javascript">
    //Duplicate the nav without pinning it to the top - this means that the other content will adjust to height of pinned nav
    var nav = document.getElementById("pinned_nav");
    var nav_copy = nav.cloneNode(true);
    nav_copy.classList.remove("w3-top");
    nav.parentElement.insertBefore(nav_copy, nav);
</script>

...
```

Since this seemed less error prone than just copy and pasting the HTML block.

But it's still rather clunky and I just wondered if there was a simpler way I was missing.

Other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386870/how-to-prevent-the-page-loosing-the-height-of-fixed-navbar-and-slipping-under-it) which are not w3css specific suggest using a fixed margin to skip a pinned toolbar but I can't see how to determine this margin height with a responsive navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Javascript script to get the height and append it however you want to use it.

```js
function getHeight() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("pinned_nav");
  var nav_height = nav.offsetHeight; //append this var where you need to.
  alert(nav_height);
};

window.onload = getHeight();
window.onresize = getHeight(); //edit, added for if you resize the page
```

```css
#pinned_nav {
  height: 100px;
  /*as example */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="pinned_nav" class="w3-top"></div>
```

**EDT**

Added resize event subscription.

Comment: Thanks -  that's better than duplicating the html element which I didn't like at all.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!

Comment: Actually though you totally answered my question - turns out my question was wrong!  Using the offsetHeight (setting sibling.topMargin for example) doesn't recalculate if the page is re-sized. You can add more javascript to fix this but this starts to get annoying enough that you may as well use bootstrap or some other framework and I was trying to avoid the jquery  + kitchen sink approach here.   So have gone back to the clunky but simple duplicate of element

Comment: Yes, I updated it with a resize event, but if you are planning to make this code longer jQuery would make it easier, well at least for me.